# How do I remove passwords from a file in SVN?

Tags: svn, passwords

I am using SVN to store my project files.
The project has become bigger and new devs are about to join.
I hardcoded passwords into a file that I need to keep private.
How do I hide those passwords from any new users I add to the SVN repo?

I can cahnge the passwords in the file to xxxxxx and check the file in,
but I know other users can just check the history on that file to find the password.

I'm hoping for a simple solution that doesn't involve setting up a new repo and checking in all the code initially into that repo with the files xxxxx out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[svnadmin obliterate](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal)
is what you are searching for. Unfortunately it is not yet implemented.
So in fact you will have to dump the repo, filter out the file and set it up again.

Answer (score 4):

You should change the passwords themselves and not worry about past passwords in the source code. As a general practice, you should change your various passwords regularly anyway.

You can just reload the whole repository (not sure how that affects history - haven't tried this before) but it won't solve the problem for the future - if another developer does the same thing, you'll have to deal with it somehow again. (It'll also become a regular problem if you follow best practices and change passwords periodically - after every change, you will have a password left in the source. If you re-use passwords in different places, you'll leave a chain of passwords in the source code this way that could be used to access those other places.)

You should keep passwords out of the source code as much as possible and segregate developer passwords from passwords to staging and production environments.